# How can I add a new Item to my multi-type Array in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift, xcode6

When I use single-type array in swift, I can add items to my array with different kind of operations (append, +=, etc.) for example this code works:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr[0...2] = [-1, -2, -3]
arr += 6
arr.append(-3)
arr += [8, -3, 1, 2]
//arr is now [-1, -2, -3, 4, 5, 6, -3, 8, -3, 1, 2]
```

but when I initialize my array with multi-type items, none of them work:

```
var arr = ["Hello", -3, 4.5, "Hi"]
var arr2:AnyObject = ["hi", -3.4, 2]
arr[0...2] = [-1, -6.7, "hello"] // Cannot assign to the result of this expression
arr.append(1.2) // 'NSArray' does not have a member named 'append'
arr += [1, "Error", -3.2] // Could not find an overload for '+=' that accepts the supplied arguments
arr2.append("hello") // 'AnyObject' does not have a member named 'append'
arr.arrayByAddingObject("This works!")
arr2.arrayByAddingObject("This works too!")
```

I realize that when I use AnyObject, my array becomes a NSArray (actually NSMutableArray) How can I make a normal swift array with AnyObject type so I can use useful operations like '+=' or functions like append.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must declare the Array as `AnyObject[]`

```
var arr: AnyObject[] = ["Hello", -3, 4.5, "Hi"]
var arr2: AnyObject[] = ["hi", -3.4, 2]
arr[0...2] = [-1, -6.7, "hello"]
arr += "hello"
arr.append([1, "Error", -3.2])
arr2 += ["hi", "hiya"]
arr2.append("hello")
```

There seems to be a bug when you try to add an array with a negative floating point value

```
arr += [1, "No Error", 3, -3]
arr += [-1, "No Error", 3, 3]
arr += -3.2 // no error
arr += [1, "Error", -3.2]
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. `arr += [1, "Error", -3.2]` still fails. As does `arr.arrayByAddingObject("This works!")` and 
`arr2.arrayByAddingObject("This works too!")`

Comment: That's a bug.. I tested it, it does work. Not a reason to down vote.

Comment: I'm afraid you're just wrong. You used different methods to the ones that failed for the OP. `arr += [1, "Error", -3.2]` gives **error: could not find an overload for '+=' that accepts the supplied arguments**. Try it.

Answer (score 2):

So, you can resolve your first 4 errors by declaring the arrays as:

```
var arr:Array<Any> = ["Hello", -3, 4.5, "Hi"]
var arr2:Array<Any> = ["hi", -3.4, 2]

arr[0...2] = [-1, -6.7, "hello"]
arr.append(1.2)
arr += [1, "Error", -3.2]
arr2.append("hello")
```

Now that they are Swift `Arrays` rather than `NSArrays`, you can't call `arrayByAddingObject` on them.

It seems like a cast to `NSArray` would work, but that causes the compiler to fail (in a playground).